# How to login after successful registration

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, authentication

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .error {
            color: red;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .div1 {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            margin-top: -19px;
            margin-bottom: -25px;
            margin-left: -19px;
        }

        .copy {
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 6px 20px;
            border-style: ridge;
        }

        .copy1 {
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 6px 28px;
            border-style: ridge;
        }

        .copy2 {
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 4px 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    include_once 'connect.php';
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $DateOfBirthErr =
        $departmentErr = $ageErr = "";
    $name = $email = $username = $password = $DateOfBirth = $department =
        $age = "";

    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST[ "name" ] ) ) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input( $_POST[ "name" ] );
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name ) ) {
                $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }

        if ( empty( $_POST[ "email" ] ) ) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input( $_POST[ "email" ] );
            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if ( !filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }

        if ( empty( $_POST[ "username" ] ) ) {
            $usernameErr = "Username is required";
        } else {
            $username = test_input( $_POST[ "username" ] );
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username ) ) {
                $usernameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }

        if ( empty( $_POST[ "password" ] ) ) {
            $passwordErr = "Password is required";
        } else {
            $password = test_input( $_POST[ "password" ] );
            $hashed_password = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
            // check weather password is alphanumeric
            if ( !preg_match( '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,}$/',
                    $password ) ) {
                $passwordErr = "Password must be alphanumeric and atleast 6 characters 
       long!";
            }
        }

        if ( empty( $_POST[ "Date_of_birth" ] ) ) {
            $DateOfBirthErr = "Date Of Birth is required";
        } else {
            $DateOfBirth = test_input( $_POST[ "Date_of_birth" ] );
        }

        if ( empty( $_POST[ "department" ] ) ) {
            $departmentErr = "Department is required";
        } else {
            $department = test_input( $_POST[ "department" ] );
        }

        if ( empty( $_POST[ "age" ] ) ) {
            $ageErr = "Age is required";
        } else {
            $age = test_input( $_POST[ "age" ] );
        }

        if ( $nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $usernameErr == "" &&
            $passwordErr == "" ) {
            $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
            $rs = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $check );
            $da = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs, MYSQLI_NUM );
            if ( $da[ 0 ] > 0 ) {
                echo "Username Already in Exists<br/>";
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`id`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` 
      ,   `Date_of_birth` , `department` ,`age`)
             VALUES ('','" . $username . "', '" . $hashed_password . "', '" . $email . "' , 
       '" . $name . "' , '" . $DateOfBirth . "' , '" . $department . "' , '" . $age . "')";

                if ( mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) ) {
                    echo "Registered successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error( $mysqli );
                }
                mysqli_close( $mysqli );
            }
        }

    }

    function test_input( $data ) {
        $data = trim( $data );
        $data = stripslashes( $data );
        $data = htmlspecialchars( $data );
        return $data;
    }
    ?>

    <div style="padding-left: 250px" class="div1">
        <h2 style="color:#009999">Registration Form :</h2>
        <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span>
        </p>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="copy" style="margin-left: 52px">
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $nameErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="copy" style="margin-left: 48px">
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $emailErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Username: </span>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="copy" style="margin- 
         left:26px">
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $usernameErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Password: </span>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="copy" style="margin- 
       left:30px">
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $passwordErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Date Of Birth : </span>
            <input type="date" class="copy1" name="Date_of_birth">
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $DateOfBirthErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <span style="color:#0099ff">  Age : </span>
            <input type="number" name="age" class="copy" style="margin-left:62px">
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $ageErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <span style="color:#0099ff">  Department : </span>
            <select name="department" class="copy2" style="margin-left:14px">
                <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
                <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
                <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
                <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                <option value="CV">Civil</option>
                <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error">
                <?php echo $departmentErr;?>
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Register">
            <p style="color:black">Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';

session_start();
$error = "";
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'login' ] ) ) {
    // username and password sent from form 

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $_POST[ 'username' ] );
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $_POST[ 'password' ] );

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = 
       '$password'";
    $resu = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql );
    $rst = mysqli_fetch_array( $resu, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
    $count = mysqli_num_rows( $resu );

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if ( $count == 1 ) {
        $_SESSION[ 'login_user' ] = $username;

        header( "location: index.php" );

    } else {
        $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }

}
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'login_user' ] ) ) {
    header( 'location:index.php' );
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .frmlg {
            background-color: #99ffff;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .xyz {
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 12px 15px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 30%;
        }

        input[type=text],
        input[type=password] {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container frmlg">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h4 style="text-align:center">Login Page</h4>
            <div class="container xyz">
                <label for="uname"><b>Username :</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                <br><br>
                <label for="psw"><b>Password :</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                <br><br>
                <button type="submit" name="login" value="Submit">Login</button><br/><br/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px">
            <?php 
         echo $error; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( session_destroy() ) {
    header( "Location: login.php" );
}
?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION[ 'login_user' ];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query( $mysqli, "select username from users where 
       username = 
        '$user_check' " );

$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC );

$login_session = $row[ 'username' ];

if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'login_user' ] ) ) {
    header( "location:login.php" );
}
?>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<?php include_once 'session.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
    <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'amith';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, 
$databasePassword, $databaseName);
?>
```

I'm creating a simple php registration form and a login form. I have completed the registration form and thats working well, but now after submitting the registration form when they try to login to their page it should get logged in but I'm unable to get this desired result can any one guide me what changes I should do to the above code so that to obtain my result.

**NOTE:** I have not added my registration file, but I have saved that file as `index.php`

Comment: You shouldn't be storing your passwords in cleartext. "unable to get this desired outcome" is not a useful diagnostic. What is happenning? There are a lot of issues with your code. Try to seperate out the components here and solve each one.

Answer (score 0):

add this code after the successful registration code

```
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
```

and the `$username` is the posted username via the form

and then a header like

```
header('Location:welcome.php');
```

Comment: i did not understood your explanation

Comment: it was a typing mistake fixed now

Comment: can u be bit specific regarding my issue? i mean about my code

Comment: `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;` this code sets user login session to their username and you directly set a user login session after the registration process if it was  a successful one then you redirect them to home page or welcome page by that header code

Comment: that `$username` must be the username variable whatever the name is in your code if i didn't see your registration page i couldn't be sure.

Comment: i will add my registration page give me 5min

Comment: forgot the session starting methods
`ob_start();
        session_start();
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;`

Answer (score 0):

update the query part to this

```
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo "Registered successfully";
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; //sets user session to the username
    header('Location:welcome.php'); //redirects the user to the user home page
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
 }
```